# Multiplying two numbers by successive sums in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, immutability

Giving m and n as integers, I can multiply them by successive sums like this:

```
    m * n = m + m + m + ... + m (n times)
```

So, let's consider the pseudo code below:

```
    m = ... (first number)
    n = ... (second number)

    Result = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        Result = Result + m;
        n = n - 1;
    }
```

How can I implement this algorithm in F# knowing that variables are immutable? 
Put the question in another way, how can I update the variables *Result* and *n* along the successive iterations?

Can someone write this algorithm in F#?

Thank you

Foot note: I'm start to study F# and I'm complete puzzled with functional programming.

Comment: `Array.create n m |> Array.sum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can use mutable variables in F#, so your algorithm could be written like this:

```
let multiply1 m n =
    let mutable result = 0
    for i = 1 to n do
        result <- result + m
    result
```

But if you want to do it a little more the functional way, you would use recursion. In this case, an inner function that accumulates the result:

```
let multiply2 m n =
    let rec loop x acc =
        if x = 0 then acc
        else loop (x - 1) (acc + m)
    loop n 0
```

The `multiply2` function uses an inner recursive function called `loop` that accumulates the result of the multiplication in the `acc` argument. So loop calls itself `n` times and adds `m` each time to the accumulator. Once `x` reaches zero, this result is returned.

Technically, you could also write the code without the accumulator argument:

```
let multiply3 m n =
    let rec loop x =
        if x = 0 then 0
        else m + loop (x - 1)
    loop n
```

Maybe this code is easier to understand for a beginner, but it should be avoided, since it does not use [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and this leads to problems. For example, this will result in a StackOverflowException:

```
multiply3 5 1000000 // This will cause a StackOverflowException.
|> printfn "Result: %d"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Seq (lazy list like in haskell / IEnumerable like in C#) and the pipe operator:

```
let mult n (m:int) =
    Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> m)
    |> Seq.take n
    |> Seq.sum
```